# Writing in edit box of default browser in Android from other app

Tags: android, browser

I have a requirement for which I would want my app to do following things:

1. Open a predefined URL in the default browser in the device
2. Choose an edit box available in that page and enter some text "xyz" into it
3. Click a button

These three tasks should happen on the default browser itself (where the foreground activity is the default browser). For the task 1, doing that is very easy and following code can do that:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(mUrlLink));
startActivity(i);
```

I am not sure how to proceed with task 2 and 3. Also the device is not connected to the computer, and hence issuing the "shell" commands like below is also NOT an option.

```
adb shell input text "xyz"
```

Can anyone help me here? Is it even possible via some automation tool like Selenium etc or not?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class LinkActivity extends Activity {

        EditText txtLink;
        Button btnOpenLink;
        String defaultLink;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_link);

            defaultLink = "http://www.google.com";

            txtLink = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLink);
            btnOpenLink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOpenLink);
            btnOpenLink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    String page = txtLink.getText().toString();
                    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(page)){
                        Uri uri = Uri.parse(defaultLink+"/"+page);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(LinkActivity.this, "Please enter page on editText!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

Comment: This is not what I wanted. I do NOT want some URL from my App's edit box to get opened in browser. I want to open a URL (say google.com) in the browser and type some text in that browser itself which is being sent to the browser from my App. Hope you got it now.